# On h- homogeneouity of $2^{\mathbb N} - \{p\}$ for $p \in 2^{\mathbb N}$

Tags: general-topology

A space X is said to be h-homogeneous if
every non-empty clopen subset of $X$ is homeomorphic to $X.$

Is  the space $L = 2^{\mathbb N} - \{p\}$ for $p \in 2^{\mathbb N}$ h-homogeneous?

Comment: no, it is not h-homogeneous. Assuming $2^{\Bbb N}$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set. What do you denote by $2^{\Bbb N}$? What did you try to understand and solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is the Cantor space. Actually, I want to know if L is the disjoint union of clopen subsets of L each homeomorphic to L. Since L is unique up to homeomorphism ( well known) so L homeomorphic (f) to L x N  and this implies the clopen subsets f^{-1} (L x {n}) is a partition of L but still not guaranteed that they all homeomorphic to L?

Comment: This is a different question, perhaps you need to post it separately. You may review https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference explaining how to format questions better. $L$ is the disjoint union of clopen subsets of $L$ (any finite $\ge1$ or infinite number), each homeomorphic to $L$. Regarding your original question posted above, I posted an answer to it (please consider accepting it, if it does answer your original question). Welcome to MSE !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me to explain the solution is to use that $2^\Bbb N$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor middle-third set $C$. Let $A=C\cap[0,\frac13]$ and $B=C\cap[\frac23,1]$. 
If $p\in C$ then without loss of generality consider the case $p\in A$. So $C\setminus\{p\}=(A\setminus\{p\})\cup B$. Both $(A\setminus\{p\})$ and $B$ are clopen in $C\setminus\{p\}$. But $B$ is compact and $C\setminus\{p\}$ is not, hence they are not homeomorphic.

If you prefer to work with $2^\Bbb N$ (set of sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s) in a similar manner take $A$ to be all sequences staring with $0$, and take $B$ to be all sequences staring with $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The Cantor set $C$ is the unique (up to homeomorphism) compact crowded zero-dimensonal metrisable space. (Brouwer, classic theorem). $C$ is $h$-homogeneous because of that.

$C\setminus \{p\}$, for any $ p \in C$ is the unique (up to homeomorphism) locally compact, non-compact crowded zero-dimensional space.

This last space is **not** $h$-homoegeneous. Take concretely $C=\{0,1\}^\omega$, $p=\underline{0}$. Then $\{x \in C: x(0)=1\}$ is a compact and clopen subset of $C\setminus \{p\}$, while $\{x: x\neq p, x(0)=0\}$ is a non-compact clopen subset of $C\setminus \{p\}$; the former is homeomorphic to $C$ the latter to the whole space $C\setminus \{p\}$.

Other classic $h$-homogeneous spaces include $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ (the irrationals); the notion is usually only considered for zero-dimensional spaces like these.